# Components of a bounded holomorphic function on annulus

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that a holomorphic function $f$ on an annulus $A=\{z\;:\;r_{1}<\lvert z\rvert<r_{2}\}$ has a unique decomposition $f=f_{1}+f_{2}$, where $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are holomorphic functions outside $\bar{D}(0;r_{1})$ and inside $D(0;r_{2})$, and $\lvert f_{1}(z)\rvert \to 0$ as $\lvert z\rvert\to \infty$. I am asked to show that if $f$ is bounded on $A$, then so are $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$. I tried using "local" formulae for the functions $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$: in a smaller annulus $B=\{z\;:\;r_{1}+\epsilon<\lvert z\rvert<r_{2}-\epsilon\}$,
$$ f_{1}(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_{1}} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z} \:d\zeta, \quad f_{2}(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_{2}}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z} \:d\zeta $$
where $\gamma_{1}$ and $\gamma_{2}$ are circles about the origin of radii $r_{1}+\epsilon$ and $r_{2}-\epsilon$, oriented clockwise and counterclockwise, respectively. I'm having trouble with this approach because of the denominator in the integrand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose any $r \in (r_1, r_2)$. We know that $f_2$ is bounded on $B := \{ z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant r\}$ by compactness, and that $f_1$ is bounded on $C :=\{ z : \lvert z\rvert \geqslant r\}$, by a similar argument (the same if you know what "analytic at $\infty$" means).

If $f$ is bounded on $A$, then $f_2 = f - f_1$ is bounded on $A\cap C$ as the difference of two bounded functions there, hence $f_2$ is bounded on $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) = A$. Similarly, $f_1 = f - f_2$ is bounded on $A \cap B$, hence on $(A \cap B) \cup (A\cap C) = A$.

Comment: thank you.. it was a multi-part problem and i felt that i needed to use an earlier part for some reason